# scapy packet.hasLayer(http.HTTPrequest) not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

I am trying to filter out http requests in scapy. I used hasLayer() function by scapy but it is giving an error.

```
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http
```

These are imports

```
def handle_packets(packet):
  if packet.hasLayer(http.HTTPRequest):
     print(packet)
```

This is the function which receives packets from this line of code.

```
scapy.sniff(iface = interface, prn = handle_packets)
```

If I do just print(packet) in handle_packets function then it prints packets with no errors but when I add that if statement it is giving me an error.

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

AttributeError: hasLayer
```

I am using python3 on ubuntu20.04.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226880/discussion-between-angelo-and-aven-desta).

Comment: Just for reference, `haslayer` has be deprecated in favor of `in`. From the docs: "true if self has a layer that is an instance of cls. Superseded by 'cls in self' syntax.".

Answer (score 3):

Firstly there packet has no attribute `hasLayer`. it should be all lowercase `haslayer`. Secondly use IP layer instead of `http.HTTPRequest`.

```
import scapy.all as scapy

def handle_packets(packets):
   for packet in packets:  
      if packet.haslayer(scapy.IP):
         print(packet)
      else:
         print("Doesn't have IP layer")

scapy.sniff(iface = interface, prn = handle_packets)
```

Comment: well, you can use `__dict__` to list all the attributes of a packet.   `packet.__dict__`